# Finding the equation of the curve. (Differential Equation)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the equation of a curve passing through $(1,1)$ where the $x$-intercept of the tangent line from any point $(x,y)$ is equal to the $y$-intercept of the normal line from the point.

Based on my understanding on the given problem. I've came up of this DE but I'm not sure if its correct:
$$m=\frac{dy}{dx} \implies m=\frac{y-y_1}{x-x_1}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y-y_1}{x-x_1}$$ where, $${x_1}=1$$ $${y_1}=1$$

Will i use seperation of variables or applying Exact DE?

Comment: I got a different answer. If you could show your steps, I'll see where they went wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1392877/differential-equation-how-to-solve-for-the-equation-of-a-curve-passing-through)

Comment: oh, we have the same question but i can't understand the answer on that link.

Comment: I don't know what "applying Exact DE" means, but why not try both and see what works?